# Calculate the maximum number of items allowed based on a fixed given value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of items in this dataframe:

```
Items   Calories
Beer      320
Hotdog    200
Popcorn   100
Coca-Cola  75
```

I need to calculate the fewest number of items I can have from the list to achieve `400` calories. Any suggestions?

I have calculated the total value of the calories, and I got stuck there.

```
row_total = df_calories['Calories'].sum()
```

Comment: So 2 items in this case? Can you only eat an item once?

Comment: Should the sum of calories of the chosen items sum upto 400 exactly?

Comment: actually, if you can count items multiple times, this is the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). If you can't count multiple times, just sort, starting from lowest to highest and use `cumsum`. the last row before the cumulated sum is 400 gives the solution

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1: If it’s not just “with how few can you go *over*”, it’s the knapsack problem with or without repetition, and (so) the greedy sorting solution is not always optimal.

Comment: You are right, withput repetion you Country wirh multplicity 1. Anyway, the point i wanted to make: without repetition the sorting solution is optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot pick a single item multiple times.

1. Sort by calories

```py
df = df.sort_values(by=['Calories'], ascending=False).reset_index()
```

Output

```
   index    Items  Calories
0      0     Beer       320
1      1   Hotdog       200
2      4    Sweet       160
3      2  Popcorn       100
```

2. Take cumulative sum & pick the first element where sum is greater than 400

```py
idx = df[(df['Calories'].cumsum() > 400) == True].index[0]
df[0:idx+1]['Items'].tolist()
```

Output

```
['Beer', 'Hotdog']
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: It does. Thank you!

Comment: Well, in that case you can accept the answer, so that it get's archived :)